# Azure DeviceTwinStatusCallBack - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, azure, symbols

I am working with Microsoft Device Twins tutorial [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-twin-getstarted#create-a-device-app). Using maven 3.5.0 and java 1.8.0_144.

My service app is building without any errors, but the problem is with a device app.
After copy-pasting code from the tutorial and trying to build the project with command "mvn clean package -DskipTests" I receive this error:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DeviceTwinStatusCallBack
[ERROR]   location: class com.mycompany.app.App
```

There is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>simulated-device</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>simulated-device</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
  <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.33</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

DeviceTwinStatusCallBack isn't available on Microsoft Azure documentation. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I just made my own class implementing IotHubEventCallback:

```
protected static class MyTwinCallback implements IotHubEventCallback
{
    public void execute(IotHubStatusCode status, Object context)
    {
        System.out.println("IoT Hub responded to device twin operation with status " + status.name());
    }
}
```

and my startDevice Twin method now looks like:

```
client.startDeviceTwin(new MyTwinCallback(), null, dataCollector, null);
```